Manually create a bridge network for KVM guests with one guest running a DHCP server
When we create a default bridged network in Libvirt it create a bunch of interfaces:

virbr0 with an IP 192.168.122.1/16
vnet0 with no IP address showing up as it is "plugged into a VM". Within the VM the same mac address of vnet0 shows up with an IP of 192.168.122.16 (e.g)

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

How do I create a bridge interface, br0, with an IP on the host machine? I created one with brctl and it seems to work, but I don't know if that's the right approach.
How do I create a vnetX interface for a guest VM that gets "plugged into" the same virtual switch as br0. Do I use something like qemu-bridge-helper for this or is there a way to use brctl or ip command for this?
Provide internet connectivity to all the VMs in a NATed mode.
Make sure their DHCP requests are confined to the virtual switch associated with "br0" interface, i.e, it works only for the VMs and not outside the network.

Sorry for the long post, I am trying to learn more about networking and this will be something of a bed rock where I can do more experiements with PXE booting, self-hosting DNS, test firewalls etc. Just want a simple NATed network of VMs with the capability to run my own DHCP, DNS, etc without leaning into Libvirt's tools.


When we create a default bridged network in Libvirt it create a bunch of interfaces:

When you create a bridge network with libvirt, it creates a single interface, the bridge device (e.g., virbr0). Additional interfaces are only created when you boot a virtual machine with one or more network devices. These will be attached to bridges by libvirt based on the network configuration you have provided.

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

Since you're using libvirt, the simplest answer is to create a libvirt bridge network with the desired network configuration. For example, we can create a new libvirt network my-network like this:
virsh net-define /dev/stdin <<EOF
<network>
  <name>my-network</name>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='br0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <ip address='192.168.168.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.168.10' end='192.168.168.200'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
EOF
virsh net-start my-network
virsh net-autostart my-network

This will result in a new bridge device, br0, with address 192.168.168.1:
$ ip addr show br0
732: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:83:aa:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.168.1/24 brd 192.168.168.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Because we've configured dhcp on this network, libvirt will have set up a DHCP server for us that will respond to requests from devices attached to this bridge:
$ ps -fe | grep my-network
dnsmasq  2440968       1  0 08:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/my-network.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper
root     2440969 2440968  0 08:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/my-network.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/libexec/libvirt_leaseshelper

This will also create appropriate iptables rules in the nat table to handle NAT for devices on the network:
$ iptables -t nat -S
-N LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
.
.
.
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.168.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.168.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.168.0/24 ! -d 192.168.168.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.168.0/24 ! -d 192.168.168.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.168.0/24 ! -d 192.168.168.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

You will also get some rules in your filter table FORWARD chain:
$ iptables -S 
-N LIBVIRT_INP
-N LIBVIRT_OUT
-N LIBVIRT_FWI
-N LIBVIRT_FWO
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.168.0/24 -o br0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o br0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.168.0/24 -i br0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i br0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i br0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i br0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i br0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i br0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o br0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o br0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o br0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o br0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT

This is a persistent configuration; because we've configured the network to autostart (virsh autostart my-network), libvirt will re-create this configuration for you when your system boots.
You attach virtual machines to this network when create them. If you're using virt-install, that might look like:
virt-install -n my-example-vm --network network=my-network ...

This will result in a libvirt virtual machine with an <interface> element that looks something like:
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:a5:e0:3f'/>
      <source network='my-network'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
    </interface>


It is possible to perform all of this configuration manually. For example, you can create and configure the bridge device:
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip addr add 192.168.168.1/24 dev br0
ip link set br0 up

Manually create appropriate firewall rules:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.168.0/24 ! -o my-network -j MASQUERADE

Configure and run a dnsmasq instance to service DHCP requests on this network (I'm not going to show this in the question).
Attach virtual machines to the bridge:
virt-install -n my-example-vm --network bridge=br0

Etc.
But: None of the above configuration will be persistent. The process of creating a persistent network configuration varies between distributions (see e.g., NetworkManager/nmcli, systemd-networkd, Netplan, etc).
Making a service like dnsmasq start automatically will involve writing a systemd service unit.
It's worthwhile to learn how to do all of these things, but that can take some time and there are many opportunities for mistakes. The most pragmatic solution is to use libvirt to create all of this configuration for you.
